# Запрет редактирования html

Tags: php, javascript, html, форма

Всем привет , возник такой вопрос.
Есть ли возможность , запретить пользователю редактировать именно "html"
теги в форме textarea ?
например в textarea по умолчанию такой код

```html
<div class="fottextb">
           <p align="center" class="fottext1">Contact Us</p>
           <p align="center" class="fottext2">Tel:</p>
</div>
```

Нужно , чтобы пользователь мог редактировать обычный текст но тэги html не редактировались , Возможно ли?

Comment: Если их не надо редактировать,  зачем их показывать? сделайте 3 поля ввода или используйте свойство `conenteditable`.

Comment: дело в том что так можно подключить большой код , отредактировать его и вставить в файл , а из index.php указать путь к этому файлу.
Тем самым редактируя этот файл . в index.php автоматически будет меняться текст который берется из этого файла.
А без кода html . придется для каждой записи создавать отдельный файл контента.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `contentEditable` для обычного `div`, а если вам нужно отправлять данные из `textarea`, то можно в процессе редактирования, либо перед отправкой, копировать все в `textarea`, который будет иметь свойство `Hidden`.

В данном примере все сразу копируется в `textarea` с `id="code"`.

```js
$('.fottextb').each(function(){
  this.contentEditable = true;
});

// перемещение кода в textarea
$('.fottextb').bind( 'DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
  $('#code').html($('.fottextb').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fottextb">
  <p align="center" class="fottext1">Contact Us</p>
  <p align="center" class="fottext2">Tel:</p>
</div>

<textarea id="code" hidden></textarea>
```

Comment: Только пользователь при редактировании может удалить внутренние теги совсем

Comment: Не могли бы вы , подробнее описать логику работы этого скрипта? 
Мне нужно именно чтобы , html сущности в textarea редактировать не могли , а вот строки могли . вот еще пример.
<p align="center" class="fottext2">Tel:</p>
Нужно что бы код <p> редактировать не могли , а строку находящуюся в нем Tel: - могли редактировать , вот я и спросил возможно ли это , и делает ли это ваш скрипт?